# float divs with clear & fill width

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I have a problem, i want to set 3 floated divs and on the bottom I would like to have a footer. So I got these two solutions, but it does not work. Please check out the image:

[image]

Here the problem is that the content is not not cleared, so the footer does not change position:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"><div class="content"><div class="right">
  <div style="clear:left;"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>


.container {
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.center {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.right {
  width: auto;
}

.content {
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.footer {
  height: 202px;
  margin: -202px auto 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

If i clear the content, I get the result that the right div goes to the next line:

[image]

thanks!

Comment: could you show all the html needed for this, even better create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: thanks, great idea, i will set up a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around a little bit. I think your html structure wasn't right for the effect you were trying to create.

Here is a new example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="left">
   </div>

   <div class="center">
   </div>

   <div class="right">
   </div>

   <div style="clear">

   <div class="content">
   </div>

   <div class="footer">
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container { 
    height: auto !important; 
    min-height: 100%; 
}

.left {   
    float: left; 
    width: 20%; 
    max-width: 200px; 
    min-height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
.center { 
    float: left; 
    width: 80%; 
    max-width: 500px; 
    min-height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
.right {  
    width: auto; 
    min-height: 100px;
    background: green;
}

.content {
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: yellow;
}

.footer { 
    height: 202px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    position: relative; 
    background: purple;
}
```

I rearanged everything in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LJQCx/2/

I hope this is what you trying to achiev.

Comment: thanks, yes that was what i was looking for, i my code i forgot to add the same margin-bottom value to the content as to the footer, here my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Holzi/Ey2DD/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code hope it will help check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arun_/bj4NS/)

```
<div class="page-wrap">
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <p>I am Left</p>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        <p>I am Center</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>I am Right</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <p>I am Footer</p>
</div>

* { margin: 0;}
html, body { height: 100%;}
.page-wrap {min-height: 100%;/* equal to footer height */margin-bottom: -142px; }
.page-wrap:after { content: ""; display: block;}
.footer, .page-wrap:after { /* .push must be the same height as footer */ height: 142px;}
.site-footer {}
.container{ width:100%;}
.left{ float:left; width:25%;}
.center{float:left; width:50%;}
.right{float:left; width:25%;}
```